# Showing that the group $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\left<(m,n)\right>$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I am given the problem of showing that

> the group $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/\left<(m,n)\right>$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(m,n)=1$,

but I'm not really sure how to approach it.

I think I am supposed to somehow use the fact that for such $m,n$ we have that $$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$$ but I am unsure on how to connect my given set to these or if this is even the right approach? I would definitely prefer hints on as to how I may see this connection so that I can truly understand the problem and how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can show that $\langle (m,n) \rangle = \langle m \rangle \times \langle n \rangle$.

Comment: @AlanWang $\langle (m,n)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z$ and $\langle m\rangle\times\langle n\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, so no.

Comment: If $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then the map $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$, $(a,b)\mapsto na-mb$ is a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is the subgroup generated by $(m,n)$. Conversely, suppose it is cyclic and $\gcd(m,n)=d>1$, so $m=dm_1,n=dn_1$. Then it contains an element of finite order, that is, the residue class of $(m_1,n_1)$, so it is finite of order say $k$. In particular, $k(1,0)=0$ and $k(0,1)=0$. This is easily seen a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I think about it. Your mileage may vary.

If $N\triangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup and $\phi$ and automorphism of $G$, then $G/N\cong G/\phi(N)$ via

$$ gN\leftrightarrow \phi(gN) $$

(note that $\phi(gN)=\phi(g)\phi(N)\in G/\phi(N)$).

In particular, we can apply the automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ associated with the matrices

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \ell & 1\end{pmatrix} $$

in order to get isomorphisms

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}^2}{\langle (m+kn,n)\rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z^2}}{\langle (m,n)\rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}^2}{(\langle m,n+\ell m)\rangle}. $$

This allows us to apply the Euclidean algorithm, ending up with

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}^2}{\langle (m,n)\rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}{\langle (\gcd(m,n),0)\rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle\gcd(m,n)\rangle}\times\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle0\rangle}. $$